# Is at least one location sent by location services after calling requestLocationUpdates?

Tags: android, android-location, android-fusedlocation

When setting up receiving location update with `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates`, I need to make sure I get at least one location.

For example, if the device has been still for a long time, after calling `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates` does it fire with last known location? Or do I have to call `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience you must call `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation()` to be guaranteed an immediate location object, and even that method may return `null` right after device reboot.

`LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates()` will give you a call back with a location when a new or relatively recent location is available that matches your request parameters in terms of accuracy, energy, etc., but if no location that matches your parameters is available it may not call back for a while. For example, if you request a high accuracy location that requires GPS, and the GPS hasn't been used recently and the devices is in a location preventing GPS signal reception, you may not see a callback until the device obtains GPS signals again.

Comment: Thanks. So you're suggesting I must call `getLastLocation`? Haven't read about this requirement.

Comment: For your best chance at getting an immediate location, yes.